# Comparison of boiling points

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point, halides

I was comparing boiling points of $\ce{CHCl_3}$ and $\ce{CH_3Cl}$. According to me B.P. of $\ce{CHCl_3}$ should be higher due to it's higher molecular mass than $\ce{CH_3Cl}$, but the answer is opposite ,ie. B.P. of $\ce{CH_3Cl}$ $\gt$ B.P. of $\ce{CHCl_3}$.Why?

Answer (score 4):

Molecular mass has NO pertinence to BP, water and ammonia.  Look up the BP of perfluorocyclohexane, hexafluorobenzene, and the hydrocarbons.  If I want to volatize iron, ferrocene.  If I want to volatize iron more, $\ce{Fe(hfac)_3}$ where the ligand is the bidentate enolate anion of 1,1,1,5,5,5-hexafluoro-2,4-pentanedione.  Big MW.  What are the MW and BP of $\ce{UF_6}$?  $\ce{-Si(CH3)_3}$ also confers volatility.

Boiling points are more about polarizability, intermolecular van der Waals and such. Bigger molecules are overall electronically floppy.  Benzene, toluene, xylenes – nice BP steps, but not because of MW. Look up $\ce{SF_6}$ bp.  $\ce{I(CF3)_7}$ boils near 0 °C.  Calculate that MW, and its vapor’s mass/liter at STP compared to dry air at 29 g/liter.

Answer (score 3):

> but the answer is opposite ,ie. B.P. of $\ce{CH3Cl}$ > B.P. of $\ce{CHCl3}$.

Really?

$\ce{CH3Cl}$ has a boiling point of **−24** °C. It is a **gas**.

$\ce{CHCl3}$ has a boiling point around 61 °C.

---

Edit: **Your argumentation is valid, there was probably just some confusion in the notes.**