# Boiling points of ethylene, formaldehyde and oxygen

Tags: intermolecular-forces, boiling-point

The boiling points of ethylene, formaldehyde and dioxygen are $\pu{-103.7 ^\circ C}$, $\pu{-19 ^\circ C}$, and $\pu{−183 ^\circ C}$, respectively. I expect formaldehyde to have the highest boiling point of the three because of dipole moment mostly due to the carbon-oxgyen bond. However, I don't know why ethylene has a higher boiling point than dioxygen.

Different from [this similar question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8246/comparision-of-boiling-points/8247#8247), where the atoms involved are of very different size, molar mass, and polarizability, the structure and electronic structure of ethylene and dioxygen are more similar. They both have a single conformation, but they have different symmetry, which might have same bearing on the entropy change during phase transition. I know that both the $\ce{C-C}$ bond in ethylene and the $\ce{O-O}$ bond in dioxygen have a bond order of 2, but dioxygen is paramagnetic while ethylene is not.

The latent heat of vaporization is [6.8 kJ/mol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heats_of_vaporization_of_the_elements_(data_page)) for dioxygen and [13.7 kJ/mol](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C74851&Mask=4) for ethylene, so enthalpy seems a major contribution to the difference in boiling point.

What are the differences in intermolecular interactions in liquid $\ce{O2}$ compared to liquid $\ce{H2C=CH2}$ underlying the difference in normal boiling point?

Comment: *Et tu Brute...* Second answer you linked answers that.